# Google Cloud can't find default credentials when trying to run docker image

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to run a Docker image through a Google Cloud proxy and despite my best efforts Google Cloud continues giving me this error:

> Can't create logging client: google: could not find default
>   credentials. See
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information.

Whenever I try to run my Docker image using this command:

```
sudo docker run dc701c583cdb
```

I have tried updating my `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to the path of my key file.
I have successfully logged in to Google Cloud using the `gcloud auth application-default login` command.
I've defined and associated my project in Google Cloud.

I am attempting this in order to run an open source project. I'm quite sure I created the Docker image correctly. I have a feeling the issue is coming from the fact that I am not correctly connecting the existing project to my Google Cloud.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I am using Docker 18.06.1-ce and Google Cloud-SDK 219.0.1. Running on a virtual linux machine with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: A wild guess on my part ... perhaps sudo isn't passing your environment variables through?  Perhaps run `sudo bash` and then try and run the commands in the newly created shell as root.  If that works, then maybe a `sudo -E` option might work where the environment is passed through to the sudo environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running the `google/cloud-sdk` container from Docker Hub in a newly-created Ubuntu 18.04 instance, the container's `gcloud` automatically inherits the instance's user configuration. Give it a try: run that container and then run `gcloud info` inside of it.

As such, I believe you might be doing something wrong. I recommend you take a look at [the aforementioned container](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/) to see how that can be made to work.